# How can I fix these intersecting faces?

Tags: 3d-printing

New to 3d printing and really want to get some of my models to work, could someone please explain in a "newbie" way on how I can go about fixing these intersecting faces? I watched a video but all it says is to push them in and this seems a bit more confusing than that because it was a cube and not a humanoid.[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I managed to fix some of the intersecting faces but I was sort of just guessing, I added the .blend file, also - are thin faces / sharp edges / overhang faces as important as intersect faces or can I get away with those with 3d printing?

Comment: no, it needs to be perfectly non-manifold watertight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could activate the *Mesh:3D-Print Toolbox* addon, check all, then in *Edit* mode you can visualize the intersecting faces:

[image]

Delete these faces, then *Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes*:

[image]

Check again, there will still be some intersecting faces, you can fix it manually:

[image]

Comment: I did this and then used the 3d builder tool and I'm down to 3 intersecting faces, will that work with 3d printing or is that still too much?

Comment: @Cazrel it needs to be perfectly manifold/watertight, needs to be zero intersecting faces. probably you will have to manually fix the remaining faces since this approach will not work perfectly.

Comment: 3d builder always fixes the manifold edge issue, so I just have to get the faces proper.

Comment: @Cazrel i've inspected the remaining non-manifold stuff and in my opinion it would be too difficult and too tricky for a newbie to fix those remaining internal faces. you will need to go through more tutorials to get more familiar with editing meshes or hire someone to do it for you unfortunately. basically you have to fix the internal faces at the eyes/head portion and you could merge by distance 0.8m the lower vertices at the boots area. but maybe someone on here has the time and can fix them and provide you with a finished blend file.

Comment: yes as Harry says there must be zero intersecting faces

Comment: @Cazrel I took the time to fix the remaining non-manifold stuff because it would be too difficult for a newbie. https://blend-exchange.com/b/b6xrSzGo but please refrain from posting similar questions that require these types of fixes. I recommend you go through a few tutorials on modeling to get you more familiar with vertices, edges, faces and Face Normals and manifold geometry if you plan to delve deeper into 3D printing. and can you please mark moonboots answer if it helped you.

Comment: I've been using Blender for around a year and a half but tbh all I've really done is rigging and some basic stuff, I'll mark moonboots answer as he was helpful with what he showed me, I did try looking at 3d printing tutorials but I couldn't find any that went in-depth enough with humanoids etc. Like I was saying though 3d-builder always manages to fix the non-manifolds for me it just leaves a lot of intersecting meshes which seem to be because of how old the models are. Thank you for the help, I guess I've gotta try to sort these intersecting faces out on the one you helped me out on.

Comment: Just curious, what turned the mesh blue?

Comment: @Cazrel under [Viewport Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html) tick the checkbox *Face Orientation* so you will see inverted face normals (red).  It's recommended to turn this option on when you try to fix meshes.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it was easier to tell what was happening, thanks

Comment: Actually super helpful lol, it was a guessing game before - thank you

Comment: One other question, so if I fix all the manifolds and all the intersecting faces, is that most of my worries gone or are the other things a major problem like zero faces / thin faces / sharp edge / overhang faces?

Comment: from what I understand, thin faces or sharp edges for example, will warn you that your machine may not be able to print such a thin geometry. Overhang faces highlight the faces that will need support underneath